# C# the operator ">>=" - How does it work?

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

I wonder what the ">>=" operator in C# does. Can anyone tell me?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's the right-shift assignment operator.  From MSDN:

An expression of the form

```
x >>= y
```

is evaluated as

```
x = x >> y
```

except that x is only evaluated once. The >> operator shifts x right by an amount specified by y.

[>>= Operator (C# Reference)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/23as4533.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

x >>= y is the same as doing x = x >> y

It's just like += but with bit shifting operators.

Answer (score 2):

Like C,

```
x >>= y
```

is the same as:

```
x = x >> y
```

This is similar to all the other `op=` operators like `+=` and `/=`. The `>>` operator is bit shifting to the right.

For example, the variable `x` with decimal value `5010` (in binary, `0011001010`) can be bit-shifted two bits right with:

```
x >>= 2
```

and it will become `000011002`, or `1210`.

Answer (score 2):

`>>=` is a bitshift to the "right". e.g. you have a integer variable containing the value 4. It is coded in binary 100. After the operation `i >>= 1` the variable contains the value 2 (coded in binary 10).

```
 int i = 4;
 i >>= 1;
 // i is 2 now
```

Answer (score 2):

`x>>=y` is just a shorter way of `x = x >> y`... You shift x for y bit to the right.

Answer (score 2):

`"x >>= y" is equivalent to "x = x >> y"`

see also:
http://sharpertutorials.com/c-operator-list/